# Дженерик для описания объекта Typescript

Tags: typescript, типы, typescript-типы

Я пишу React хук для сортировки полей таблицы. Для универсальности решил использовать дженерики Typescript.

Данные `sortData` представляют собой объект вида `{[id:string]:{id, name, ...} }`. А в `items` лежат ключи `id`.

Пример объека `sortData`:

```
data: {
    '7': {
      id: 7,
      first_name: 'Юрий',
      last_name: 'Юрьев',
      company: 'РЖД',
      office_position: 'Машинист',
      phone_number: '82323233232',
      email: 'appdafs@adas.ru',
      creation_date: '2022-01-02T16:43:53.159Z',
      client_key: 'GM5VNYKeaXtK',
      valid_until: '2022-03-06T00:00:00.000Z',
      isAccept: true
    },
    '8': {
      id: 8,
      first_name: 'Дмитрий',
      last_name: 'Кликов',
      company: 'ЭТК',
      office_position: 'Директор',
      phone_number: '84334883483',
      email: 'psdafsdaf@sadfsd.ru',
      creation_date: '2022-01-03T16:43:53.159Z',
      client_key: 'G894M8LyyquK',
      valid_until: '2031-04-19T00:00:00.000Z',
      isAccept: true
    },
    '9': {
      id: 9,
      first_name: 'Павел',
      last_name: 'Павлов',
      company: 'Дикси',
      office_position: 'Продавец кассир',
      phone_number: '84939393923',
      email: 'fsvs@fsdf.ru',
      creation_date: '2022-01-30T16:43:53.159Z',
      client_key: 'G9jZe4aJy2Uo',
      valid_until: '2022-01-30T00:00:00.000Z',
      isAccept: true
    },
...
}
```

Я написал такое объявление функции :

```
const useSortableData = <T extends object, U extends keyof {[id:string]:T}>(items: U[], sortData: {[id:string]:T}, config: {
    field: string;
    direction: "desc" | "asc" | undefined;
  } = {field: "id", direction: 'asc'}) => {
```

Теперь я хочу сортировать `items` по полю объекта `sortData`:

```
sortableItems.sort((a, b) => {
        if (sortData[a][sortConfig.field] < sortData[b][sortConfig.field]) {
          return sortConfig.direction === 'asc' ? -1 : 1;
        }
        if (sortData[a][sortConfig.field] > sortData[b][sortConfig.field]) {
          return sortConfig.direction === 'asc' ? 1 : -1;
        }
        return 0;
      });
```

Но ts ругается на все строчки вида `sortData[a][sortConfig.field]`.

> Элемент неявно имеет тип "any", так как выражение типа "string" не может использоваться для индексации типа "{}".
> В типе "{}" не обнаружена сигнатура индекса с параметром типа "string".

Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне доказать, что выражение типа "string" все таки может использоваться для индексации типа "{}"?

Пробовал разные варианты дженериков, но ошибка плюс минус такая же.

Полный код хука:

```
export const useSortableData = <T extends object, U extends keyof {[id:string]:T}>(items: U[], sortData: {[id:string]:T}, config: {
    field: string;
    direction: "desc" | "asc" | undefined;
  } = {field: "id", direction: 'asc'}) => {
  const [sortConfig, setSortConfig] = useState(config);
  
  const sortedItems = useMemo(() => {
  const sortableItems = [...items];
    if (sortConfig !== null) {
      sortableItems.sort((a: U, b: U) => {
        if (sortData[a][sortConfig.field] < sortData[b][sortConfig.field]) {
          return sortConfig.direction === 'asc' ? -1 : 1;
        }
        if (sortData[a][sortConfig.field] > sortData[b][sortConfig.field]) {
          return sortConfig.direction === 'asc' ? 1 : -1;
        }
        return 0;
      });
    }
    return sortableItems;
  }, [items, sortConfig]);

  const sortingField = (field: string) => {
    let direction: "desc" | "asc" | undefined =
      sortConfig.direction === "desc" ? "asc" : "desc";
    if (sortConfig.field !== field) {
      direction = "desc";
    }
    setSortConfig({ field, direction });
  };

  return { items: sortedItems, sortConfig, sortingField };
}
```

Пример вызова

```
interface ClientDataInterface {
  first_name: string;
  last_name: string;
  company: string;
  office_position: string;
  phone_number: string;
  email: string;
  id: number;
  client_key?: string;
  valid_until?: string;
  isAccept?: boolean;
}

const Component = ({allIds, data}) => {

const { items, sortConfig, sortingField } =
    useSortableData<ClientDataInterface>(allIds, data);

 const getClassNamesFor = (name) => {
    if (!sortConfig) {
      return;
    }
    return sortConfig.key === name ? sortConfig.direction : undefined;
  };
  return (
    <table>
      <caption>Products</caption>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>
            <button
              type="button"
              onClick={() => requestSort('name')}
              className={getClassNamesFor('name')}
            >
              Name
            </button>
          </th>
         {/* … */}
        </tr>
      </thead>
      {/* … */}
    </table>
  );
}
```

Comment: что имелось ввиду в такой записи: `{[id:string]:T}`? Добавь пример вызова, с конкретными данными

Comment: Добавил массив данных пример вызова.

Comment: _что имелось ввиду в такой записи: `{[id:string]:T}`_?

Comment: Я пытался показать тайпскрипту, что ключи типа "string" могут использоваться для индексации sortData. Но видимо ему нужны конкретные ключи из этого объекта. А как их дженериком показать я не могу додуматься.